# Adding SSL Certificate Breaks Windows Authentication for some users Windows Server 2012 IIS 8.0

Tags: ssl-certificate, windows-authentication, iis-8, windows-server-2012

Members,

I am encountering an issue when trying to use Windows Authentication and an SSL Certificate.

I am trying to move a Web application from a Windows Server 2003 virtual server (IIS 6.0) to a Windows Server 2012 R2 Virtual server (IIS 8.0).

I ported the application to our new UAT server and all seemed to work fine until I installed an SSL Certificate on the web server. After that, SOME users in Europe are having problems with the Windows Authentication. The application is seeing their `AUTH_USER` variable populated but are continually propped to login again and again.

If they access the site with HTTP instead of HTTPS it works fine.
For myself and other testers in the US, it works fine with HTTPS or HTTP.

I have the following Authentication features set.

Server Level: 
Anonymous Authentication = Enabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled
Providers:   Negotiate  (First Option)   NTLM (Second Option)

Site Level: 
Anonymous Authentication = Disabled 
Windows Authentication = Enabled
Providers:   Negotiate  (First Option)   NTLM (Second Option)

This application is used within my companies local IntraNet.
The certificate was generated by corporate IT tool.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Rich

Comment: A new tester was able to experience the issue with both http and https.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by changing the permissions on the folder.
Refer to https://serverfault.com/questions/462100/iis-8-folder-url-and-permissions

I used the option to add the 'Everyone' User/Group
[Everyone selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPB9h.jpg)